# How to minimize Card spacing in Bootstraps 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I just created 4 card using bootstraps 4.5 version but the spacing is really bad and I do not know how to reduce the spacing of card you can the image if you still confuse

[image: Result of Card]

```css
.card {
width : 55%;
min-height: 100;
margin:  2%; 
}
.card-img-top {
height: 150px;
object-fit: cover;
}
.card-body{
box-shadow: 0 0 20px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card text-md-center">
            <img src="Nike.jpg" class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Shoes</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text</p>
              <a href="#">Buy</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card text-md-center">
            <img src="chevrolet.jpg" class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Car</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text</p>
              <a href="#">Buy</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card text-md-center">
            <img src="asuslap.jpg" class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Laptop</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text</p>
              <a href="#">Buy</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card text-md-center">
            <img src="asusphone.jpg" class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Phone</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text</p>
              <a href="#">Buy</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I have searched it in google but I still not find it (How to reduce spacing of Card), maybe you can help me

Comment: you want is create 4 card in 1 row/line?

Comment: yes sir, I want to create 4 card in 1 row but the spacing is very bad

Comment: The large spacing is because you added `width: 55%` in your card CSS. If you want to have reduced space but keep the same card width, you can consider to use a smaller column span instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't problem about the width card, you can remove `width : 55%;` in your CSS. It would be better.

OR

You can change the value in every `col-md` class. The spacing the of every card is caused by that.

Comment: That's NOT the Bootstrap way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I added a `flex-display` to your `.row` class and justified everything in the center. Spacing looks fine to me.

```css
.card {
width: 55%;
min-height: 100;
margin:  2%; 
}
.card-img-top {
height: 150px;
object-fit: cover;
}
.card-body{
box-shadow: 0 0 20px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card text-md-center">
            <img src="Nike.jpg" class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Shoes</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text</p>
              <a href="#">Buy</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card text-md-center">
            <img src="chevrolet.jpg" class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Car</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text</p>
              <a href="#">Buy</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card text-md-center">
            <img src="asuslap.jpg" class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Laptop</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text</p>
              <a href="#">Buy</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Bootstrap way to do so is to dynamically adjust the column width depending on the width of the browser/screen. Do not set the width manually. Let the media query breakpoints do the job.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card text-md-center">
        <img src="http://placehold.jp/320x180.png" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Shoes</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text</p>
          <a href="#">Buy</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card text-md-center">
        <img src="http://placehold.jp/320x180.png" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Car</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text</p>
          <a href="#">Buy</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card text-md-center">
        <img src="http://placehold.jp/320x180.png" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Laptop</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text</p>
          <a href="#">Buy</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card text-md-center">
        <img src="http://placehold.jp/320x180.png" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Phone</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text</p>
          <a href="#">Buy</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.card {
  /* width: 55%; */
  min-height: 100;
  margin: 2%;
}

.card-img-top {
  height: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card-body {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ayrdgnhk/)